# Using NSTrackingArea in an NSView that is unattached to a window?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Basically, I want an "invisible" NSView covering my entire screen. I will add an NSTrackingArea to that, so that I get global mouse events as my cursor moves about the screen.

```
-(void)setTrackingArea 
{
    view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:[NSScreen currentScreenForPoint:[NSEvent mouseLocation]].frame];

    NSTrackingArea *area = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[NSScreen currentScreenForPoint:[NSEvent mouseLocation]].frame options:NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways owner:view userInfo:nil];

    [view addTrackingArea:area];

    [area release];

    //[[window contentView] addSubview:view];

    //I don't want to add the view to a window, as all tutorials say.
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent 
{
    NSLog(@"Exit"); //Never firing
}
```

Is this possible? Using NSViews and NSTracking Areas without a window?

Comment: You can't have a view that's not in a window, but you should be able to create an invisible window that covers the whole screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an invisible view is definitely not something you want to do.  Look into the [`addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask::`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsevent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask%3ahandler%3a) class method on `NSEvent`.

For example, here's how you would add a monitor for a movement of the mouse:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSMouseMovedMask handler:^(NSEvent *mouseMovedEvent) {
    //do something with that event
}];
```